# Creating a list of lists after accessing a tuple

Tags: python

I am trying to create a nested list after accessing the first element of a tuple in a nested list. Below is the sample input.

```
nested = [
         [('wow', 'NN'), ('loved', 'VBD'), ('place', 'NN')],
         [('great', 'JJ'), ('touch', 'NN')]
         ]
```

**Below is the sample code for use**

```
mapped_pos = {
    # Nouns
    'NN':wordnet.NOUN,
    # Verbs
    'VB':wordnet.VERB,
    # Adjectives
    'JJ':wordnet.ADJ,
    # Adverbs
    'RB':wordnet.ADV,}

normalised_sequence = []
for i in nested:
    for tuples in i:
        temp = tuples[0]
        if tuples[1] == "NNP" or tuples[1] =="NNPS":
            continue
        elif tuples[1][:2] in mapped_pos.keys():
            temp = lemmaword.lemmatize(tuples[0],pos=mapped_pos[tuples[1][:2]])
            x = ''.join(temp)
            normalised_sequence.append(x)

print(f"\nLemmatised words:\n{normalised_sequence}")
```

**Below is the given output**

```
Lemmatised words:
['wow', 'love', 'place', 'great', 'touch']
```

**The expected output should be this as shown below;**

```
[['wow', 'love', 'place'], ['great', 'touch']]
```

**Which then permits a final outcome of the following below when supplied any given list as input;**

```
[
'wow love place', 
'great touch'
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You append individual values to `normalised_sequence`, but you want to add sublists. Try this:

```
normalised_sequence = []
for i in nested:
    sublist = []

    for tuples in i:
        temp = tuples[0]
        if tuples[1] == "NNP" or tuples[1] =="NNPS":
            continue
        elif tuples[1][:2] in mapped_pos.keys():
            temp = lemmaword.lemmatize(tuples[0],pos=mapped_pos[tuples[1][:2]])
            x = ''.join(temp)
            sublist.append(x)
    normalised_sequence.append(sublist) # or normalised_sequence.append(' '.join(sublist)) is you want to merge the items to strings
```